# How to avoid to update record in self referenced model due to not refers to itself and also not to be duplicate references

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model, self-reference, rails-models

I have self referenced model:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :allergens
  has_many :cqnames, as: :cqnable
  has_many :inclusions
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :inclusions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cqnames, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :inclusions, allow_destroy: true
  translates :name, :description
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true


  def self.get_children(ing)
    @tree ||= []
    if ing.ingredients.nil?
      return @tree
    else
      @tree << ing.ingredients
      get_children(ing.ingredients)
    end
  end
end
```

I have to avoid self referencing to the same record and also to the records already referenced when the respecting record is updating.

Experiment with before_validation...:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :hokus
  has_and_belongs_to_many :allergens
  has_many :cqnames, as: :cqnable
  has_many :inclusions
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :inclusions
  has_many :inverse_inclusions, :class_name => "Inclusion", :foreign_key => "ingredient_id"
  has_many :composites, :through => :inverse_inclusions, :source => :component
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cqnames, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :inclusions, allow_destroy: true
  translates :name, :description
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true


  require 'set'
  def self.pokus(ing)
    avoid = Set.new([self])
    q = true
    if ing.ingredients.present?
      ing.ingredients.each do |record|
        q = false if avoid.include? record
      end
    end
    q
  end

  def hokus
    Component.pokus(self)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit of a mess.  But I'll give you a pointer on how you may build your list without duplicates.

```
require 'set'
def self.get_children(ing)
  tree = Set.new
  avoid = Set.new([self])

  recursive = lambda {|recs|
    recs.ingredients.each do |record|
      pass = false
      if avoid.include? record
        pass = true
      else
        tree << record
        avoid << record
      end
      recursive.call(record.ingredients) unless pass
    end
  }
  recursive.call(ing.ingredients)
  tree.to_a
end
```

I've done a fare bit of recursive work like this so I believe that will do what you're hoping to do.  Although I haven't tested this particular piece of code.

If you'd like to see a depth first record duplication method I've written you can see it in my gem [poly_belongs_to](https://github.com/danielpclark/PolyBelongsTo/blob/master/lib/poly_belongs_to/dup.rb#L20-L36) .  I use a variation on **Set** I built which basically does the same thing I demonstrated here with the **avoid Set**.  I explain Set in my blog post here [Different Collection Types in Ruby](http://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/03/26/different-collection-types-in-ruby/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Dan. I'm absolute newbie in coding and I can't imagine what your code does. I studied it a lot (include your blog post and PBT). Generally I have to avoid circular reference (in any depth) in my self-referencing model class. I can imagine the algorithm - BMO appropriate logic can be realized either in model level (before_save/update) or in controller (form) level (not to offer the inappropriate selection in relevant select box) maybe both, but my coding skills are still really very poor and I don't know how to code it...

Comment: Set is a unique list.  It's like Array but will only keep one of each object.  So it will do most of the work for you.  The way you're going about designing things looks like it will be painful to maintain.  I would avoid using has_and_belongs_to_many if you can avoid it.  The simpler you can keep it the better off you will be.  What you're looking to do isn't exactly a newbie thing.  You may be interested in looking into an existing gem that will do hierarchy stuff for you.

Comment: That self-referencing model is in fact  - has_many :ingredients, :through => :inclusions - not HABTM.
It isn't the purposeless design. All of that associations are working well. I know it is a bit complex. I already found https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree and https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry but BMO it is not what I'm looking for. I need exactly the self-referencing has_many :through association and as I wrote, It pretty works. All I have to do is to avoid that circular self-reference. But it's over my current skills.

Comment: For many years I was preparing and analysing design of our apps but no coding. In the last few years I usually built it on Drupal 6/7 (also a complex ones) but it had many limitations which I decided to break by learning to code Ruby (Rails) apps. If you are familiar with c9.io IDE I can grant you the access to my dev env  better to understand what I'm working on.

Comment: Experiment with the individual parts in a irb/rails console and see how they work.  The **Set .add?()** method is key for what you want.  See my other answer here.

Comment: I already understand your code and just now I'm experimenting with parts of it in the rails console :-) Things seems to be a bit more complicated due to checking both, parents and ancestors trees ;-)

Comment: What is the code construction if I want to apply this as condition for before_validation (in case if avoid.include? record = "true" then before_validation fires "false" and stops to save/update current Component followed by appropriate error message)?

Comment: There isn't enough room to go into that here.  That particular point won't work so you may want to open a new question.  As to before_validation you can just use a method name `before_validation :my_method_name`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: I am already experimenting with it but still does not work. This is only my experimental code not final solution... (see end of edited Question)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simpler version that should get the job done then this may do.

```
require 'set'
def self.get_children(ing)
  tree = Set.new

  recursive = lambda {|recs|
    recs.ingredients.each do |record|
      recursive.call(record.ingredients) if tree.add?(record)
    end       
  }

  recursive.call(ing.ingredients)

  tree.to_a
end
```